# Есть формула расчета восход заход солнца по координатам?

Tags: php

Имеются:

1. Широта
2. Долгота
3. Высота над уровнем моря
4. Текущая дата

Требуется формула расчета времени восхода и заката солнца. В сети нашел только на википедии, но там непонятно. Есть что-то более понятное?

Comment: [взгляните, может пригодится?](https://coderoad.ru/704088/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/7784f4b2c7838b893e9b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что я нашел в результате поисков https://sunrise-sunset.org/api - это то что нужно!

Comment: офигеть это есть встроенное в PHP https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-sun-info.php .... ктоб знал...